# rails problem with multi model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I'm trying to process the dsc files from an ubuntu's sourcecode repository to populate a rails application, for this I used 3 models:

```
class Architecture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :srcpkgs, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :binpkgs, :through => :srcpkgs, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :srcpkgs, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :binpkgs, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end

class Srcpkg < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :binpkgs, :dependent => :delete_all
  belongs_to :architecture

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :binpkgs
  attr_accessor :architecture_id, :bdeps
  validates_presence_of :architecture_id
end

class Binpkg < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :srcpkg, :touch => true
  belongs_to :architecture

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :srcpkg
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :architecture
  attr_accessor :architecture_id, :srcpkg_id
  validates :architecture_id, :presence => true
end
```

and using a controller admin with:

```
def populate
  notice = nil
  pname = '/tmp/dpkg_1.15.5.6ubuntu4.5.dsc'
  p = Pkg.new pname
  binpkg = []
  bdep = []
  if not Srcpkg.find_by_name(p.source.to_s)
    arch = Architecture.find_or_create_by_name(p.architecture.to_s)
    arch.save
    srcpkg = Srcpkg.find_or_initialize_by_name(p.source.to_s)
    p.bdepends.each do |b|
      b1 = Binpkg.find_or_initialize_by_name(b)
      b1.save
      bdep.push(b1.id)
    end
    srcpkg.update_attributes({:name => p.source.to_s,
                           :version => p.version.to_s,
                           :stdversion => p.stdversion.to_s,
                           :bdeps => bdep,
                           :arquitecture_id => arch.id})
    srcpkg.save
    p.binary.each do |b|
      b1 = Binpkg.create
      b1.name = b
      b1.srcpkg_id = srcpkg.id
      b1.arquitecture_id = arch.id
      b1.save
    end
    notice = "Package successfully processed"
    logger.debug " ---- here #2 ---- "
  else
    logger.debug " ---- here #3 ---- "
    notice = "Package not processed, it was already added"
  end
  flash[:notice] = notice
  redirect_to "/architectures/#{arch.id}"
end
```

this doesn't create neither the srcpkg object, nor the binspkgs objects
before this, I also tried this:

```
p = Pkg.new pname
params = { :architecture => {
    :name => p.architecture.to_s,
    :srcpkgs_attributes => [{
        :name => p.source.to_s,
        :version => p.version.to_s,
        :stdversion => p.stdversion.to_s,
        :bdeps => [],
        :binpkgs_attributes => []
    }]
  }
}
p.binary.each do |b|
  params[:architecture][:srcpkgs_attributes][0][:binpkgs_attributes] << {:name => b.to_s}
end
if not Srcpkg.find_by_name(p.source.to_s)
  arch = Architecture.find_or_create_by_name(p.architecture.to_s)
  arch.update_attributes(params[:architecture])
```

even with:

```
src = Srcpkg.new(params[:architecture][:srcpkgs_attributes][0])
src.save
```

I searched for than a week now and tried other methods.. but no one worked.. so, any idea?
thanks a lot

Comment: Okay 2 questions. 1 - Is save returning true or false? 2 - If false what does src.errors.full_messages return?

Comment: it's returning false in srcpkg and binpkg the architecture is created, and srcpkg.errors.full_messages = 'Architecture blank'

Comment: Hmm got me.   My suggestion would be to use the rails console and try each line from the populate method to track exactly what is going in and where it is failing.  From the messages you are failing on one of the validate_presence validations.

Comment: yes, but I don't know why the 'Architecture blank' message... I'm passing the arch.id (which has the number) and that message appears :D

Comment: Thanks you, huntsfromshadow :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code.. now, without update_attributes it creates some binpkgs but no srcpkgs or other binpkgs objects like this where I set the architecture_id:

```
p.binary.each do |b|
  if not Srcpkg.find_by_name(b)
    b1 = Binpkg.new
    b1.name = b
    #b1.srcpkg_id = srcpkg.id
    b1.arquitecture_id = arch.id
    logger.debug "b1.arquitecture_id = '#{b1.arquitecture_id}'"
    b1.save!
    logger.debug b1.id
  else
    if Srcpkg.find_by_name(b).srcpkg_id.empty?
      b1 = Srcpkg.find_by_name(b)
      b1.srcpkg_id = srcpkg.id
      b1.save!
    end
  end
end
```

I´m using the save! to validate the messages, but.. this code failed in save! returning "Validation failed: Architecture can't be blank" , but the logger.debug returns a valid number .. how can it be??